# Flask app error: "The requested URL was not found on the server"

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-session

I'm trying to run Flask application, showing book overview page with the ability to submit user's review. But I've faced 2 problems:

1) When I'm trying to run the code below, the url for "/books/553803700" redirects me back to home page.

I guess there is an issue with

```py
review = db.execute("SELECT review FROM reviews WHERE review_by = :review_by", {"review_by": current_user}).fetchone()
```

2) if I'm commenting that string above, page works. But when I'm trying to submit review, it shows "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

application.py file:

```py
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, redirect, flash, jsonify
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

....
### some app configuration, other routes
...

@app.route("/books/<isbn>")
def book(isbn):
    try:
        if globals()["session"]["username"]:
            current_user = globals()["session"]["username"]
            book = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE isbn = :isbn", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchone()

            ### here is that string
            review = db.execute("SELECT review FROM reviews WHERE review_by = :review_by",
                                {"review_by": current_user}).fetchone()

            if review is True:
                return render_template("book.html", book=book, review=review)

            else:
                return render_template("book.html", book=book)


    except:
        return redirect("/login")


@app.route("/books/<isbn>/review", methods=['POST'])
def review(isbn):
    review = request.form.get("review")
    current_user = globals()["session"]["username"]
    db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (isbn, review_by, review) VALUES (:isbn, :review_by, :review)",
               {"isbn": isbn, "review_by": current_user, "review": review})
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return redirect("/book/" + isbn)
```

book.html file:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block getin %}

    <h1>{{ book.title }}</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Title: {{ book.title }}</li>
        <li>ISBN: {{ book.isbn }}</li>
        <li>Author: {{ book.author }}</li>
        <li>Year: {{ book.year }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block user_info %}
    <h2>Would you like to leave your review?</h2>

    {% if review %}
    <div class="user-review">
    {{ review }}

    </div>

    {% else %}
        <form name="submit-review" action="/book/{{book.isbn}}/review" method="POST">
        <textarea type="text" name="review" class="form-control" placeholder="Leave your review here">
        </textarea>

        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

    {% endif %}

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px">
        GoodReads reviews:
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Would really appreciate your help to fix those 2 problems

Answer (score 0):

To solve the second error:

> Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
>   entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

You need to add the back slash `/` to route `@app.route("/books/<isbn>)`. It will be similar to this:

```
@app.route("/books/<isbn>/")
def book(isbn):
   #...
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Look at your action's value.

```
...
    <form name="submit-review" action="/book/{{book.isbn}}/review" method="POST">
...
```

Let replace it by this one:

```
...
    <form name="submit-review" action="{{ url_for('book', isbn=book.isbn) }}" method="POST">
...
```

Else try to delete it simply.

```
...
    <form name="submit-review" action="" method="POST">
...
```